# Possible to undo rake db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, schema

I just mistakenly performed `rake db:schema:load` on my development database and it wiped all the data I have been using to perform my tests. I can regenerate some of it using a rake task I wrote, but is there a way to simply undo it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using your development database to perform tests? All your test data should be in your test database.

Comment: Apologies, I misspoke - I meant development, not testing. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to undo a schema load. There are only rollbacks for migrations. Sorry!

Comment: Also, rollbacks do not bring back data, just FYI.